# Link does not transform to post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my code which could be found here: https://github.com/marcvanderpeet12/bloccitfinal

On app/views/_favorite.html.erb I included the following link: <%= link_to [post, Favorite.new], method: :post do %>

the method: :post should make it a post but if I run the relevant page (http://localhost:3000/posts/48/)  and try to click the favorites button i still get this error

No route matches [GET] "/posts/48/favorites"

Thought im pretty sure my route are set up right Any thoughts what might go wrong here?

Comment: Share your routes file contents please !

Comment: He posted a link to the whole github project.

Answer (score 1):

You need a route for action show in your favorites controller 
In your routes.rb you have `resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]`
which means you don't have a route to show the post that you just submitted. You need to do this :

```
`resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy, :show]
```

and create the show action in your favoritesController, then create a view that renders that action.

Comment: Could you eloborate on what you mean @RailsOuter

Answer (score 0):

Your `favorites_controller.rb` is empty. You need to define your `create` and `destroy` actions.

For the create action, grab your post and create a favorite using your `user` object.

`favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: @post)`

Check and save it.

Your destroy action could be something like:

`favorite = current_user.favorites.find(params[:id])`

where `:id` is the ID of a `favorite` object.